# Binding a dropdownlist and then adding a new listitem

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I have a `DropDownList` which I initialize in a function called `CreateChildControls` before adding it to the `Controls` collections. I then override the `Render()` method and then render the `DropDownList`. The web part inherits from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart`.

I bind the `DropDownList` in my web part like this:

```
private void BindClientTypes()
{
    DataTable dt = DB.GetAllClientTypes();

    if (dt == null)
    {
        ltGlobalErrorMsg.Text = GlobalErrorMessage;
        ltGlobalErrorMsg.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ddlClient.DataSource = dt;
        ddlClient.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddlClient.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlClient.DataBind();
        ddlClient.Items.Insert(0, PleaseSelectItem);
    }
}
```

If I try to set the `SelectedIndex` of the `DropDownList` after calling `DataBind`, I get an error which says the control cannot have multiple selected items.

That code works fine, and I can set the `SelectedIndex` after the data bind if I comment out this line:

```
ddlClient.Items.Insert(0, PleaseSelectItem);
```

Can anyone explain why this wouldn't work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("yourtext", "yourvalue"));
```

When you set the 'selected' property you are setting it to that ListItem's instance so if you have more ListItems that you are reusing then they will all get the same value which is probably causing the issue you are experiencing.

To illustrate the problem see this example with 2 dropdownlists:

```
ListItem item1 = new ListItem("1", "1");
ListItem item2 = new ListItem("2", "2");
ListItem item3 = new ListItem("3", "3");

ddlTest.Items.Add(item1);
ddlTest.Items.Add(item2);
ddlTest.Items.Add(item3);

ddlTest2.Items.Add(item1);
ddlTest2.Items.Add(item2);
ddlTest2.Items.Add(item3);

ddlTest2.SelectedValue = "2";
```

Setting `ddlTest2`'s selected value actually sets ddlTest as well since they share the same items list.  If you run this bother `ddlTest` and `ddlTest2` will have the exact same selected value even though only `ddlTest2` was set.

Comment: What was bothering me was I never set the selected index to "PleaseSelectItem"... However, the selected index of the drop down list was always 0 and I was adding the list item at the index 0. So I guess it took it upon itself to set the selected index to 0. 

Yes, If I do not reuse the instance then the code works fine. 

Thanks. This has been a good lesson. So never reuse the instance across multiple drop down lists.

Answer (score 1):

Where is PleaseSelectItem declared? If you add the same instance of a listitem to many dropdownlists you are liable to get this problem.

Comment: Yes, I am reusing the instance. Okay Let me try it without reusing the same instance.